# SQL SELECT to get company status based on working hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute a SQL SELECT query to get all the stores within a city and also have a field to inform if the store is within working hours or not.

This is the SQL I have so far:

```
$day  = date('w');
$hour = date('H:i:s');

SELECT a.id, a.rating, a.name, a.image, b.cityName
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM tbStore a, workingHour b 
        WHERE a.id = b.id_store 
        AND b.weekDay = '$day' 
        AND b.hourOpen <= '$hour' 
        AND b.hourClose >= '$hour') 
    ) as 'open'

FROM tbStore a, tbCity b
WHERE b.url = '$url'
AND a.id_city = b.id
ORDER BY open
```

The way I'm checking this value is as a boolean, so the 'open' field needs to be 0 (closed) or 1 (open).

It's kind of working... But the problem is, if just 1 store is within working hours, all of the others will be 'open' as well, instead of just that specific store.

I also saw some sql statements where people use CASE instead of another select, so any other type of code can be used, as long as the final result is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redefining the `tbStore a` and losing the restriction by `$url`.  You probably just need to change:

```
SELECT 1 FROM tbStore a, workingHour b
```

To:

```
SELECT 1 FROM workingHour b
```

Comment: I also had to rename the table letter. Instead of `workingHour b` I had `workingHour c` because of the city table being `b`. But now it's working! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have just rewrite you query  using explict join way

```
SELECT 
      a.id
    , a.rating
    , a.name
    , a.image
    , b.cityName
    , when( c.id_store is not null then 1 else 0 end) as open
FROM tbStore a
inner join tbCity b on a.id_city = b.id
LEFT join workingHour c on a.id = c.id_store 
WHERE b.url = '$url'
AND c.weekDay = '$day' 
AND c.hourOpen <= '$hour' 
AND c.hourClose >= '$hour'
ORDER BY open
```

Comment: It kind of worked.. The result only contain the stores when they are 'open', if they are closed, they don't appear on the results. What I need is to get all of the stores, but have a field set to `0` or `1` based on the working hours.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade   . ..  there is a wrong alias on id_store case  .. i have udapte the answer ..